# How many different colored Yoshis are there?

Tags: super-mario-world

In Super Mario World, Yoshis had abilities depending on their color and Koopa Shells. If a blue Yoshi licks up a Koopa Shell, it could temporarily grow wings until it is swallowed or spit out. If a red Yoshi licks up a Koopa Shell, it could spit it back out as a trio of fireballs.

How many different colored Yoshis are there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Super_Mario_World#Colored_Yoshis), there are four colors of Yoshi:

- Red, which spits fireballs when spitting out a Koopa shell,
- Blue, which will grow wings to fly when holding a Koopa shell in its mouth,
- Yellow, which will pound the ground (creating "sand clouds") while holding a Koopa shell in its mouth
- Classic Green, which will do all of the above, depending on the color of Koopa shell it eats.

Comment: beat me to it! :)

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that the different colored Yoshi's get the ability that matches both their color and the color of the shell. Ie. if a red Yoshi eats a blue shell, it will be able to fly for a while until it spits out the shell, which if it does will be spit out as fireballs.

Answer (score -1):

According to the wiki, there are actually 11 colors of Yoshi. Soon, like the black and white Yoshi, have special powers that set them apart from the rest. The colors of Yoshi are as follows:
Green
Red
Blue
Yellow
Light blue

Purple
Orange
Black
White
Pink
And someone defunct brown there is also a variety of the character called baby Yoshi. The size are Yoshi‘s that have freshly at shell of eggs. They are more related to the Yoshi‘s Island cannon, and less so the super Mario cannon.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).